# Adding parameters from a FORM to URL with queried page

Tags: php

I have a search page which is queried from index.php
example : `http://localhost/sgc/admin/index.php?page=search`

then i created a form within this page to search users by names

```
<form role="form" method="get" action="" class="form-horizontal">
<input type="search" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
</form>
```

the problem is when the input is submitted it redirects to the index.php and adding the paramteres to the index page `http://localhost/sgc/admin/index.php?name=`

required URL format is to be `http://localhost/sgc/admin/index.php?page=search&name=`

can it be achived using php or i have to use javascript

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Hidden input field with name=page & value=search. What does the `type=search` mean? Shouldn't that be `type=text`?

Comment: @Wrikken search is a valid input type, it is in the HTML5 specs.

Comment: @Edward: ah, thank you, always something missing in my HTML5 knowledge... I'll get there eventually ;)

Comment: You need to set the action="" to the url of the page with the query string, e.g. http://localhost/sgc/admin/index.php?page=search&name=

Comment: doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

try :

After submision : 
your url : ttp://localhost/sgc/admin/index.php?page=search&name=YOUR_STRING

Comment: i can't get it, what do you suggest?